# Java Swing/JFrame Listeners

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, actionevent

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make a 
simple beginners program that takes in the users
 input of the temperature and outputs it converted
 into celsius. I think I have something hooked up wrong
 with the listeners though because it gives an output but
 it's always zero. I'm not really sure what I did wrong 
with the listeners and the action events.

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class TemperatureConversionJFrame extends JFrame{
private final JTextField temperatureF;
private final JLabel result;
public int fahrenheit = 0;

public TemperatureConversionJFrame(){
    super("Celsius Conversion");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    temperatureF = new JTextField("Enter temperature in fahrenheit to be converted");
    add(temperatureF);
    result = new JLabel("Result in Celsius");
    add(result);


    TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();

    temperatureF.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{

 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        int F;
    int results;
            F = Integer.parseInt(temperatureF.getText());
            results = 5/9 * (F - 32);
result.setText(String.valueOf(results));
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TemperatureConversionJFrameTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  TemperatureConversionJFrame temperatureConversionJFrame = new  TemperatureConversionJFrame(); 
            temperatureConversionJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 temperatureConversionJFrame.setSize(275, 100); 
 temperatureConversionJFrame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I have something hooked up wrong with the listeners

Well the first thing to do is add a System.out.println(...) to the listener code so see if the listener is invoked.

Assuming it is invoked then I would guess the problem is:

```
results = 5/9 * (F - 32);
```

You are doing integer division so 5/9 is always 0.

One fix is to use something like:

```
results = (F - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

Also, an ActionListener on the text field is only invoked when the Enter key is pressed.

You may want to consider using a `DocumentListener`. This is invoked whenever text is added or removed in the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Ah. I completely missed that. Thanks, it was just the logic that had it displaying 0.

Comment: @MichaelFogarty, That is why basic debugging like displaying the value of calculations should be used. It helps you narrow down where the problem is instead of guessing.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as it will allow me to. Thanks!